# SQL QUERY,Getting the difference between two time periods

Tags: sql

I want to write a query (SQL)to produce  a comparative report between two time Periods(P) and produce such a table .Below the  is the desired results .

```
Country  P1(Jan/01 to Jan/07)    P2 (Feb/02 to Feb/09)  Difference(P2 - P1)
Kenya        3                               7                    4
Uganda       5                               2                   -3
Tanzania     4                               1                   -3
Burundi      6                               5                   -1
Rwanda       4                               6                    2
Total       22
```

The data on the database is appears as a single records for specific days.

e.g.

```
Report ID      Report Desc    Country   Report Date
001             Traffic         KE      January 1, 2017
002             Court           TZ      January 5, 2017
003             Traffic         KE      February 6, 2017
004             Land            UG      January 21, 2017
005             Building        BRD     January 22, 2017
006             Traffic         RWA     February 7, 2017
```

Is it possible ??

Comment: Appreciate your detailed question, how did u got p1 and p2 and have u tried any scripting so far ?, Please tag your database

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys @BHouse ,@a_horse_with_no_name .Am working with oracle database .My report will have four parameters where the user will chose date rangers for P1 (startdate and enddate ) and do the same for P2(startdate and enddate ) thus getting two results and having the difference at the end. I would like suggestions on the query or procedure to be used to give the two columns P1 and P2 given that these records are in one table but the values are dynamic depending on the selected dates.Is it achievable??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find out how many rows per country fall into two time periods P1 (Jan 1-7) and P2 (Feb 2-9).  If that's correct, you can use a `CASE` statement nested in a `COUNT`.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
  Country, 
  P1, 
  P2, 
  P2 - P1 AS Difference
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Country,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN "Report Date" BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-07' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS P1,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN "Report Date" BETWEEN DATE '2018-02-02' AND DATE '2018-02-09' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS P2
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY Country
) src
```

Give it a try and let me know if that works.

Comment: hey ravioli ! am back again the solution works for  me ,but is possible I add a condition that will make when both P1 and P2 are 0 the row wont be returned because the query is returning everything

Comment: Hola amigo.  Of course, just add a `WHERE` clause at the end of your query: `WHERE (P2 - P1) <> 0`.  That will prevent these rows from being returned in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

If p1 and p2 are hardcoded date ranges, this is fairly easy:

```
select a.country,
       sum(a.p1_ctr) as p1, 
       sum(a.p2_ctr) as p2,
       sum(a.p2_ctr) - sum(a.p1_ctr) as difference
  from (select country,
               case when report date between <p1 start> and <p1 end> then 1
                    else 0 
                    end as p1_ctr,
               case when report date between <p2 start> and <p2 end> then 1
                    else 0 
                    end as p2_ctr
          from <single records table>) a
 group by a.country
```

If they're drawn from another table it gets a little more complicated.